# onDrawerOpened Navigation Drawer and setting textView on Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I'm attempting to reset the data from Parse.com on a TextView defined in my NavigationDrawerAdapter. I assume the easiest way of doing so would be to do so in the onDrawerOpened in my MainActivity so that it checks it everytime to ensure the users logged in or out. The issue is the text isn't setting. I'm attempting to call the layout from the MainActivity that's located in the NavigationDrawerAdapter's getView() like so:

```
  public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
            {

                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                ParseUser.getCurrentUser().fetchInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {

                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException arg1) {
                        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                       View convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_drawer_list_object, null);
                       TextView username = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtvDrawerFirstItemText1);
                       username.setText(user.getUsername());

                    }
                });

                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            }
```

Any ideas why this wouldn't be working? Can I not set the TextView that's in my NavigationDrawerAdapters getView from the MainActivity, if not how would this be accomplished then?

Comment: have you checked in "done" function whether you receive any text at all?

Comment: Yes I added a log statement and it returns the text correctly each time depending if I'm logged in or not, just never gets updated. I do get a warning on the View convertView line that says  avoid passing null as the view root though.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use,

```
Drawer mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Update Text View Here.
        mDrawerLayout.invalidate();
    }
});
```

The `invalidate()` call will redraw the Drawer Layout.

Comment: Sorry, I'm sort of new, where would this go?

Comment: Whenever you want to update the textview, use settext() then call invalidate().

Comment: What you should do is to set the text of the textView from some class variable. Now, when you want to update the text, change the value of that variable and then call the invalidate() method. This'll redraw the drawer and the new value will be fetched from the updated variable.

Comment: Tried your solution, still not working for some reason.